# In .NET, are static constructors called when a new AppDomain is created?

Tags: c#, appdomain

When I create a new AppDomain using `AppDomain.CreateDomain` in C#, will static constructors be called as asseblies are loaded inside the newly created AppDomain?

The assemblies in question have already been loaded into the current domain.

Comment: Nice question. Actually static ctors aren't called until you instantiate an object of the class, not when the assembly is loaded.

Comment: @jdv: Or if you access a static member...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No - static constructors will only be called the first time a static member is accessed or an instance is created.

The static constructor *will* be invoked once per `AppDomain` though, if that's what you were concerned about. It's not like having executed once in a different `AppDomain`, the types in the new `AppDomain` get left uninitialized :)

Note that type initializers for types *without* static constructors may be executed earlier or later than those for types *with* static constructors, and the precise implementation details [changed for .NET 4](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/01/26/type-initialization-changes-in-net-4-0).

Comment: That link to changes for .NET 4 is bad

Answer (score 4):

Check this site: http://codeidol.com/csharp/net-framework/Threads,-AppDomains,-and-Processes/AppDomains/

Here is an excerpt:

Unless you use something like thread-static fields, each AppDomain contains a copy of all static fields. All class (or static) constructors will run once within a given AppDomain. This means that if you load the same assembly in different AppDomains, each will run the class constructors, and each will contain separate values for all static fields, for example.